# How to install old R version from CRAN page

Tags: r

I downloaded R 4.0.0 version https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-4/. How can I install this version in R ?

Answer (score 0):

You can download

for windows from
cran.r-project.org › bin › base › old
Web results
Previous releases of R for Windows - CRAN

For mac
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/old/index-old.html